# python-twitter error with api.PostDirectMessage

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I was testing out code for python-twitter, and everything seems okay until I tried to get it to post a direct message to an id.

```
api.PostDirectMessage(3517181843, "some text test")
```

Which then returns

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Azizah Blackwood/Documents/GitHub/just-a-chatbot-test/chatbotwithdifferentlib.py", line 11, in <module>
    api.PostDirectMessage(3517181843, "some text test")
  File "C:\Users\Azizah Blackwood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twitter\api.py", line 3044, in PostDirectMessage
    created_at=data['event']['created_timestamp'],
KeyError: 'event'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I means the data returned to you is an empty dictionary or the dictionary doesn't have that element.

```py
data = {}
print(data['event']['created_timestamp'])
```

you will get `KeyError: 'event'`

You can try passing in `return_json=True` and see the actual response:

```py
print(api.PostDirectMessage(3517181843, "some text test", return_json=True))
```

Comment: That returns
[{'code': 214, 'message': "event.message_create.target.recipient_id: 'some text test' is not a valid Long"}]}

Comment: OK there you go